# Missing Tablayout

Tags: android, xml, tabs, android-tablayout

I am trying to create a material tab layout for the first time, but the Tablayout does not show up  as one of the possible options in my Main_Activity.xml. I have entered `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'` in my `build.gradle` so I do believe I have the correct dependencies...

**Main_Activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/LayoutDimen"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
  >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/view">

        <!--- I'd like to place my Tablayout here -->

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/output"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/outputHeight"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/output"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/outputHeight"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/youtyped"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/symbolHeight"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textColor="#0000FF"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
        android:text="@string/plus"
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:textSize="@dimen/symbolSize"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
        android:text="@string/minus"
        android:id="@+id/minus"
        android:textSize="@dimen/symbolSize"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_above="@+id/two"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/plus" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
        android:text="@string/divide"
        android:id="@+id/divide"
        android:textSize="@dimen/symbolSize"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mutiply"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/mutiply" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_below="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/numberSize"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/two"
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_below="@+id/plus"
        android:textSize="@dimen/numberSize"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/middle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/middle"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/three"
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_below="@+id/minus"
        android:textSize="@dimen/numberSize"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/end"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/end"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/four"
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_below="@+id/one"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/numberSize"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/five"
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:layout_below="@+id/two"
        android:textSize="@dimen/numberSize"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/middle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/middle"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/six"
        android:id="@+id/six"
        android:layout_below="@+id/three"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/end"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/end"
        android:textSize="@dimen/numberSize"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/seven"
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_below="@+id/four"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/numberSize"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/eight"
        android:id="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_below="@+id/four"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/middle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/middle"
        android:textSize="@dimen/numberSize"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nine"
        android:id="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_below="@+id/four"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/end"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/end"
        android:textSize="@dimen/numberSize"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/zero"
        android:id="@+id/zero"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/numberSize"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dot"
        android:id="@+id/dot"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/middle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/middle"
        android:textSize="@dimen/numberSize"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/equals"
        android:id="@+id/equals"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/end"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/end"
        android:textSize="@dimen/numberSize"
        android:background="#278a16"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
        android:text="@string/multiply"
        android:id="@+id/mutiply"
        android:textSize="@dimen/symbolSize"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/three"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/three" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:text="@string/Clear"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="@dimen/back"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/back"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_hardware_keyboard_backspace"
        android:background="#6E6E6E"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mutiply"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/mutiply" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/youtyped"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:id="@+id/squareRoot"
        android:text="@string/squareRoot"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radians"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radians"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/radians"
        android:textSize="@dimen/numberSize"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:id="@+id/pi"
        android:text="@string/pi"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/squareRoot"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/squareRoot"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/squareRoot"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:id="@+id/tan"
        android:text="@string/tangent"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pi"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pi"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/pi"
        android:textColor="#2a18ff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:id="@+id/Sin"
        android:text="@string/sin"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Square"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Cosine"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Cosine"
        android:textColor="#2a18ff"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:id="@+id/Log10"
        android:text="@string/log10"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/squareRoot"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:id="@+id/Hyperbolic"
        android:text="@string/hyp"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pi"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tan"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tan" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:id="@+id/Cosine"
        android:text="@string/cosine"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:textColor="#2a18ff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pi"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tan"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tan" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:id="@+id/Square"
        android:text="@string/squared"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Log10"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Sin"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Sin"
        android:textSize="@dimen/numberSize"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:id="@+id/Exponential"
        android:text="@string/Exponential"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Log10"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radians"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="@string/radians"
        android:textColorHighlight="#01DF01"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/degrees"
        android:id="@+id/degrees"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textColorHighlight="#01DF01"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/radians"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/radians"
        android:clickable="false"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:text="@string/log"
        android:id="@+id/log"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/equals"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:text="@string/inverse"
        android:id="@+id/inverse"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/equals"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Sin"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Sin" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sciencebutton"
        android:text="@string/negative"
        android:id="@+id/negative"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/equals"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Exponential"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Exponential" />

    <include

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="800dp"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/include"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

**toolbar_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#A4A4A4"
android:minHeight="50dp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
app:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This is my first time doing this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

**full gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ca.software.appart.calcu_everything"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile files('libs/commons-math3-3.6.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

}
```

Comment: @DanielNugent see my update.

Answer (score 0):

Add compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'` into gradle file and test again .

Code sample :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:Android="http://schemas.Android.com/apk/res/Android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.Android.com/tools" Android:layout_width="match_parent"
    Android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.techlovejump.materialdesign.MainActivity">
    <Android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:Android="http://schemas.Android.com/apk/res/Android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.Android.com/apk/res-auto"
    Android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    Android:layout_width="match_parent"
    Android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    Android:background="#ff6d7fe2"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    ></Android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <TextView Android:text="@string/hello_world" Android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        Android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        Android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>

</RelativeLayout>

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>` in your xml file where you want to place the tab layout. Hope that helps